# Django - Unable to override settings.py values from within it

Tags: django, django-settings

I am trying to override certain settings in Django's settings.py for production. Instead of using the documented approaches, I decided to add an 'if' statement to the end of the settings.py file and change certain values (which have already been set) if we are on the production machine.

```
import socket
if not socket.gethostname() == 'local':
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
```

This somehow messes up settings so that my static files are not served. Everything works fine as soon as I remove this code.

I do not understand why the staticfiles settings get messed up when I change the DEBUG value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Warning**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)
>
> This will only work if `DEBUG` is `True`.